# SQL Server Kerberos Delegation on Failover Cluster Instance

Tags: sql-server, kerberos

I am attempting to setup kerberos delegation on a SQL Server failover cluster in order to get around the double-hop issue but have hit a roadblock.

**Environment Overview**:

Four SQL Servers in two datacenters (DA01,DA02,DB01,DB02)
Two SQL Server named instances with dedicated IP addresses statically bound to port 1433 (SQINS01, SQLINS02)

Each sql instance is on a failover cluster within its datacenter (SQLINS01 may live on DA01 or DA02, SQLINS02 may live on DB01 or DB02)

Both SQL server instances run as a domain service account domain\account1

**SPN Overview**

domain\account1 has the following SPNs in place on the domain
MSSQLSvc/SQLINS01:1433 ,
MSSQLSvc/SQLINS01.domain.com:1433 ,
MSSQLSvc/SQLINS02:1433 , 
MSSQLSvc/SQLINS02.domain.com:1433

**Delegation**

domain\account1 has been configured for constrained delegation
User is trusted for delegation on the SPNs listed for Kerberos Authentication

I am attempting to test this connection as follows:
Connected from my local computer to SCLINS01 using my domain credentials that are allowed to be delegated.

Running the following command still returns the NT Authority\Anonymous Login failure:

```
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM OPENDATASOURCE ('SQLNCLI11','Server=SCLINS02.domain.com;Integrated Security=SSPI;').database1.dbo.table1
```

I have used the microsoft Kerberos Configuration Manager to verify that SPNs are configured properly.

Comment: [Are you sure you're connecting to the SQL instance via Kerberos Authentication and not NTLM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/909801/how-to-make-sure-that-you-are-using-kerberos-authentication-when-you-c)?  What does `select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id=@@spid` return?

Comment: Returns "KERBEROS"

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit; is `KERBEROS` returned when you connect to all servers in these clusters?  If one is reverting to `NTLM`, this may explain the behavior, but if you're seeing `KERBEROS` on all connections you at least have SPNs setup appropriately.  That narrows the issue down to either a delegation configuration setting or the `OPENDATASOURCE` command itself (which I normally don't use to test delegation).  I'm not currently in an environment where I can test any of this quickly, hence the comment, but hopefully this gives some options for further investigation.

Comment: Interesting it looks like it is working with LINKED SERVERS but not with OPENDATASOURCE

Comment: Really strange, I think it may be an issue with SSMS. If I open a new query and run the OPENDATASOURCE command, then replace it with the linked server command it fails. If I open a new query window and go right to the linked server command it is successful.